# Append array to itself by repeated function calls

Tags: numpy

im trying to append an array by repeatedly calling a function. When I put the append command in a loop this works fine, but not when the loop calls the function that's supposed to do the append.

```
import numpy as np
test_value = 555
i = 0
j = 0
test_array = np.empty([0, 3])  

def test(test_value, i, j, test_array):
    test_temp = []
    test_temp.append(i)
    test_temp.append(j)
    test_temp.append(test_value)
    test_temp_1 = test_temp

    test_temp_2 = np.array(test_temp_1)
    test_temp_2 = np.reshape(test_temp_2, (1,3))

    test_array = np.append(test_array, test_temp_2, axis=0)

    return test_array

for i in range(0,10):
    i = i + 1
    j = j + 2
    test(test_value, i, j, test_array)

print ("test array", test_array)
```

Ideally what would happen is that test_array gets a new row added each time its looped, but so the final print of test_array stays empty.

Cheers

Comment: The `test_array = ...` line assigns a new object to this variable, and breaks the link with the array that was passed in.  `np.append` does not work in-place (in contrast to the list append, which is in-place and faster).  So in the loop you need to use the return value; don't just throw it away.  Now if `test_array` was a list, and you used `test_array.append(test_temp_2)` your function should work.

Comment: alright so instead of `test_array = np.append(test_array, test_temp_2, axis=0)` it should look like `np.append(test_array, test_temp_2, axis=0)`? when i try that however test_array stays empty.
and what do you mean with the last sentece?

Comment: No!  Read the docs for `np.append`, better yet, look at its code.  And test it in an interactive session.  Then compare it to `list.append`.  Make sure you understand the difference.  As for the function call, study the examples in this section: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference, especially 1 vs 3.

Comment: While I understand the difference between list.append and array.append completely, using a list in the function and making it an array outside the function should work. Thanks for the quick response though.